# How to delete one shape from another in Illustrator CS4?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

I have an image (below) of two hands over a black circle. All three are currently separate paths with a fill but no stroke, all on the same layer.

How do I delete the shape of the hands from the black circle, so that afterwards I can delete the hands themselves, and just have the circle, with the shape of the hands cut out of it?

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/29y4bkn/6]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Open up the Pathfinder palette (Window > Pathfinder or Shift+Control+F9). Select one hand and the circle and press the 'subtract' button:

[image: subtract button in Illustrator CS6]

Depending on your preferences, the 'Expand' button may become clickable. If it does, click it. Repeat with the other hand.

It might be a good idea to make copies of the hand shapes in advance (and paste them in front, Ctrl+F and lock and/or hide them) so you have spare copies of the same shape.

Answer (score 3):

I got stuck on this in spite of Vincent's helpful answer. Turns out I was trying to cut one **shape** from another, as opposed to cutting **paths** from each other.

So, if your objects are shapes, you need to hold the Alt or Option key when selecting an option from the Pathfinder menu. (more info from Adobe, [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html#pathfinder))

Hope that helps!

Comment: hold alt or click on the "Expand" button as mentioned on his answer

Answer (score 2):

Clip it with [Pathfinder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6462a.html#WS12312fb24e2221162c8ac029133b8844bb1-8000) or [Clipping Mask](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html)